# Can't Prevent Google Chrome From Auto filling Field

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

This question has been asked before and I'm asking again because none of the answers worked.

I've got a form on my checkout page where I have `autocomplete="off"` in the `<form>` tag.

My form contains address information. Specifically, I have a field named `address_line_two` which should not be auto filled. So, on this input I set `autocomplete="false"` on this input field. This works on my PC, but I have video monitoring installed on my site and several of my chrome users are able to auto fill the `address_line_two` field. I also see the duplicated auto fill data in my database as a result. I am referring to the Google auto fill function that automatically populates a form with a previously saved address. Is there an updated work around to this issue?

Comment: What is so important about not autofilling this specific field?

Comment: Chrome autofills address_line_one correctly, but then autofills address_line_two with the same information as address_line_one. When you save an address in chrome, there isn't an address_line_two option anyway. If there is a technically correct approach I'm all about it but haven't seen one yet. @KevinB

Answer (score -3):

The browser is going to remember the values provided to the autocomplete attribute for future use. So for individual users that have filled out different forms made by developers with different naming conventions, the fields will populate accordingly.

Most users like autofill and want it to run. You could give your input a random auto-complete value to prevent auto-complete from running, but, it will likely slow users down.

```
 <input autocomplete="address-line2">
```

The attribute above above follows chrome's recommended settings for forms, so most liekly to grab the right string to cram into the input. That will probably net you the most correctly auto filled forms over time.

If you take this advice make sure to do the same naming convention for address line 1:

```
<input autocomplete="address-line1">
```

Please note I left out a all of other attributes and values you need for an input field to simplify the answer.

Here is some documentation I drew from.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill

This quote is from the documentation link:

"For one address input: street-address For two address inputs: address-line1 , address-line2 address-level1 (state or province) address-level2 (city) postal-code (zip code) country"